# how to retrive all commits of a special branch with gitlab api v4?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

For example, my project id is 385, and I want to retrive all commits of branch 'V3.53.5' with gitlab api v4, the url is [http://{ip}/api/v4/projects/385/repository/commits/?ref_name=V3.53.5&per_page=9999](http://xxx/api/v4/projects/385/repository/commits/?ref_name=V3.53.5&per_page=9999), the problem is that it only return some commits even with the parameter `per_page=9999`.

While gitlab api v3 doesn't have this problem. I cant get all commits with [http://{ip}/api/v3/projects/385/repository/commits/?ref_name=V3.53.5&per_page=9999](http://xxx/api/v3/projects/385/repository/commits/?ref_name=V3.53.5&per_page=9999)

But I just want to use api v4, what should I do? I don't find an answer to my question in [Gitlab API docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/commits.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GitLab API has a max 100 per page: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/#pagination

What you should do is retrieve `X-Total-Pages: <total_pages>` and iterate over each page adding the URL parameter `&page=<page>`

Answer (score 0):

I have done sth very similar with it.
I set the perpage , got the total-pages as a response and loope it.

```
req_data = requests.get(GET_PROJECT_MEMBERS_URL.format(
        project_id), headers=headers_data)
    if req_data.status_code != 200:
        return 0
    else:
        All_Pages = req_data.headers["X-Total-Pages"]
        for current_page_number in range(1, int(All_Pages)+1):
            current_resp = requests.get(GET_PROJECT_MEMBERS_WITH_ID_PAGE.format(
                project_id, project_id, current_page_number), headers=headers_data)
            current_merbersdata = current_resp.json()
            for member in current_merbersdata:
                print(member['username'])
```

And static apis

```
GET_PROJECT_MEMBERS_URL = "https://xxx/api/v4/projects/{}/members/all"
GET_PROJECT_MEMBERS_WITH_ID_PAGE = "https://xxxx/api/v4/projects/{}/members/all?id={}&page={}&per_page=20"
```